# How do I find out the value of these dwFlags constants?

Tags: c#, .net, dllimport, unmanaged

I'm looking at the MSDN documentation for [ChangeDisplaySettings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183411%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  For the dwFlags option, you can pass in 0 or one of the other listed flags.  However, I can't figure out how to reference those flags directly, nor figure out what their actual `long` value is to use in their stead.

I'm making these calls from a C# application using this:

```
[DllImport("User32.dll")]
public static extern long ChangeDisplaySettings(ref DeviceMode lpDevMode, int dwflags);
```

Is there a way I can reference the flags directly, or, barring that, find out what their actual values are?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://www.pinvoke.net to the rescue

```
[Flags()]
public enum ChangeDisplaySettingsFlags : uint
{
    CDS_NONE = 0,
    CDS_UPDATEREGISTRY = 0x00000001,
    CDS_TEST = 0x00000002,
    CDS_FULLSCREEN = 0x00000004,
    CDS_GLOBAL = 0x00000008,
    CDS_SET_PRIMARY = 0x00000010,
    CDS_VIDEOPARAMETERS = 0x00000020,
    CDS_ENABLE_UNSAFE_MODES = 0x00000100,
    CDS_DISABLE_UNSAFE_MODES = 0x00000200,
    CDS_RESET = 0x40000000,
    CDS_RESET_EX = 0x20000000,
    CDS_NORESET = 0x10000000
}

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern DISP_CHANGE ChangeDisplaySettings(ref DEVMODE devMode, ChangeDisplaySettingsFlags flags);
```

**source**: http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.changedisplaysettings

Comment: Thanks! Any idea why this wouldn't be MSDN?

Comment: Because the Win32/User32 API isn't 'platform independend' and thats the target of .NET